# How to handle same code parts in Factory Method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have classes:

```
public abstract class House{
   public string Name {set;get;}
   public SomeClass Property1 {set;get;}
   public OtherClass Property2 {set;get;}
}

public class WoodenHouse:House{
   public string WoodType {set;get;}
   public int WoodAge {set;get;}
}

public class StoneHouse:House{
  public string StoneType{set;get;}
}
```

And trying to create Factory Method patthern for this:

```
    abstract class Creator
    {
        public abstract HouseInfo Info { get; set; }

        public Creator()
        {
        }

        public abstract House FactoryMethod();
    }

    class WoodenHouseCreator : Creator
    {
        public override HouseInfo Info { get; set; }

        public WoodenHouseCreator(WoodenHouseInfo info)
        {
            Info = info;
        }

        public override House FactoryMethod()
        {
            var info = Info as WoodenHouseInfo;

            var woodenHouse = new WoodenHouse();
            woodenHouse.Name = info.Name;
            woodenHouse.Floors = info.Floors;
            woodenHouse.RoofType = info.RoofType;
            woodenHouse.WoodType = info.WoodType;
            woodenHouse.WoodAge = info.WoodAge;
            return woodenHouse;
        }
    }

    class StoneHouseCreator : Creator
    {
        public override HouseInfo Info { get; set; }

        public StoneHouseCreator(StoneHouseInfo info)
        {
            Info = info;
        }

        public override House FactoryMethod()
        {
            var info = Info as StoneHouseInfo;

            var stoneHouse = new StoneHouse();
            stoneHouse.Name = info.Name;
            stoneHouse.Floors = info.Floors;
            stoneHouse.RoofType = info.RoofType;
            stoneHouse.StoneType = info.StoneType;
            return stoneHouse;
        }
    }
```

Here is classes what contains information to create house:

```
    class HouseInfo
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public int Floors { set; get; }
        public string RoofType { set; get; }
    }

    class WoodenHouseInfo : HouseInfo
    {
        public string WoodType { set; get; }
        public int WoodAge { set; get; }
    }

    class StoneHouseInfo : HouseInfo
    {
        public string StoneType { set; get; }
    }
```

And Usage:

```
        var houseInfo = new WoodenHouseInfo{
            Name = "HouseName",
            Floors = 2,
            RoofType = "Triangle",
            WoodType = "Pine",
            WoodAge = 100
        };

        House house;

        if(houseInfo is WoodenHouseInfo)
        {
            var creator = new WoodenHouseCreator(houseInfo);
            house = creator.FactoryMethod();
            Console.Write((house as WoodenHouse).WoodAge);
        }
```

Full code [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xVc0Hj).

My problem that how to handle code duplication. I mean here is a lot of lines what fills base `House` object properties. How can i write that code only once?
Or i should not to use `Factory Method`?

**Add Populator Class**

```
class HousePopulator
    {
        public void PopulateHouse(HouseInfo info, House house)
        {
            house.Name = info.Name;
            house.Floors = info.Floors;
            house.RoofType = info.RoofType;
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
abstract class Creator
{
    public abstract HouseInfo Info{get;set;}
    public HousePopulator HousePopulator {get;set;}
    public Creator()
    {
        HousePopulator = new HousePopulator();
    }
    public abstract House FactoryMethod();
}

class WoodenHouseCreator : Creator
{
    public override HouseInfo Info{get;set;}

    public WoodenHouseCreator(WoodenHouseInfo info)
    {
        Info = info;
    }
    public override House FactoryMethod()
    {
        var info = Info as WoodenHouseInfo;

        var woodenHouse = new WoodenHouse();
        HousePopulator.PopulateHouse(Info, woodenHouse);
        woodenHouse.WoodType = info.WoodType;
        woodenHouse.WoodAge = info.WoodAge;
        return woodenHouse;
    }
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions**](https://CodeReview.Meta.StackExchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Do not update your question with insights from answers. This makes it very confusing And Is against rules of this site. If you want to review your modifications, post another question.

Comment: Also please add more context. In current state your code Is very hard to review as Its purpose remains hidden or represents a generic problem which would be off topic here. Your code does not even compile.

Comment: FYI this is more *abstract factory* than *factory method*, and I believe you will want to look into the *builder* pattern for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your factories instantiate the new objects and then fill in all of their properties with the right values. You could split instantiation from property value assignment. Your `StoneHouseCreator` could instantiate a `StoneHouse`, use a `HousePopulator` that populates the values that all objects of type `House` have in common, and then the `StoneHouseCreator` could populate the rest of the values that are exclusive to a `StoneHouse`. That same `HousePopulator` could also be used by your `WoodenHouseCreator`, which would then proceed to populate the `WoodenHouse`-specific properties.

Actually, there are two ways of doing this. Either you keep it as it was originally (i.e. using *inheritance*), give your base class a `PopulatorMethod(...)` that populates the properties of a `House`, and call `base.PopulatorMethod(...)` from your override of `PopulatorMethod(...)` in the child classes. Or you drop the inheritance between your factories completely, you make your `FactoryMethod()` implementations accept instances of `WoodenHouseInfo` or `StoneHouseInfo` depending on the implementing class, and have them use a `HousePopulator` as you have done.

If you go down the second route, you don't need an abstract parent class, although an interface would be nice, and you can move the `HousePopulator = new HousePopulator()` assignment to the individual factory classes.

If you want to philosophise about this at a higher level, these are the problems that we run into because of *inheritance*. Factories, that is the logical separation of object use from object creation, are more naturally suited to cases where you use *composition* over *inheritance*. If you are interested more in this, I would recommend reading this excellent [article](https://codeburst.io/inheritance-is-evil-stop-using-it-6c4f1caf5117) on the topic.

Comment: I update question with `Populator` class(also update fiddler). Do you mean solution like this?

Comment: There are two ways of doing this. Either you keep it as it was originally (i.e. using *inheritance*), give your base class a `PopulatorMethod(...)` that populates the properties of a `House`, and call `base.PopulatorMethod(...)` from your override of `PopulatorMethod(...)` in the child classes. Or you drop the inheritance between your factories completely, you make your `FactoryMethod()` implementations accept instances of `WoodenHouseInfo` or `StoneHouseInfo` depending on the implementing class, and have them use a `HousePopulator` as you have done.

Comment: If you go down the second route, you don't need an abstract parent class, although an interface would be nice, and you can move the `HousePopulator = new HousePopulator();` assignment to the individual factory classes.

Comment: @PhilipAtz You should add this to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simplify your class to its standard form, which is `House` needs `Name` and `Type`, then go from there.

Take it this way, if you need to create a new house, then you can write pseudo code that want something like :

```
var house = new House
{
    Name = "House Name",
    Type = new WoodenHouse
    {
        WoodType = "Pine",
        WoodAge = 100,
        Floors = 2,
        RoofType = "Triangle"
    }
};
```

Since `Floors` and `RoofType` are releated to the `House`, then you can include them into the `House` instead.

Example :

```
var house = new House
{
    Name = "House Name",
    Type = new WoodenHouse
    {
        WoodType = "Pine",
        WoodAge = 100
    },
    Floors = 2,
    RoofType = "Triangle"
};
```

then we can implement this :

```
public class House
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IHouseType Type { get; set; }

    public int Floors { get; set; }

    public string RoofType { get; set; }
}

public interface IHouseType 
{
    // define your contract
     string TypeName { set; get; }
}

public class WoodenHouse : IHouseType
{
    public string TypeName { set; get; }

    public int WoodAge { set; get; }

}

public class StoneHouse : IHouseType
{
    public string TypeName { set; get; }
}
```

and your `Creator` class can be something like this :

```
public class HouseCreator
{
    private House _house;

    public HouseCreator(House house) { house = _house; }


    public House FactoryMethod()
    {
        if(_house.Type is null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); } // it's not defined

        /*
         NOTE : 
            Floors & RoofType are shared properties, so it can be processed outside the following if blocks
         */
        var floors   = _house.Floors;
        var RoofType = _house.RoofType;


        if (_house.Type is WoodenHouse)
        {
            // process the WoodenHouse logic
        }

        if(_house.Type is StoneHouse)
        {
            // process the StoneHouse logic and save it 

        }
        return _house;// return the processed house object.
    }
}
```

It's straight forward process, and there is no need to use duplicated objects like `HouseInfo`, and the `Creator` and `HousePopulator` in current context, I don't see any usage of them, since `new` keyword does that for you. What you need might be to implement `FactoryMethod()` and `PopulateHouse()` inside `House` class, which would make more sense to me at least. The factory method would act as a handler where you process the logic to your object internally, and then pass it to the Populate method where you execute the output publicly.

So, the conversion usage might be simplified to something like this :

```
// Create a new house
var house = new House
{
    Name = "House Name",
    Type = new WoodenHouse
    {
        TypeName = "Pine",
        WoodAge = 100
    },
    Floors = 2,
    RoofType = "Triangle"
};


//Populate It 
house.Populate();
```

Another thing that might be also useful, using `Enum` in `RoofType` would me more appropriate than `string`. so this line :

```
RoofType = "Triangle"
```

can be converted to this :

```
RoofType = HouseRoofType.Triangle
```